# is there a way to make a "metafile"? (looks like a file, but read/writes get filtered through a program)

Tags: macos, mac

A file that looks like a file to 3rd party apps, but read/writes are filtered through a program.

Specifically what I want to do is to have a file that is the concatenation of several other files that a 3rd party app can read/write. It will be a text file, and the boundaries will just be pragma marks or a similar format. When the 3rd party writes to this file, the underlying program will write each section to the underlying source files. When a 3rd party app reads it, it will be constructed on the fly from the contents of the underlying files.

There are a number of uses I have for this; the most immediate one is to be able have a NEXTSTEPS.taskpaper file for TaskPaper that is composed of many NEXTSTEPS.taskpaper files from many different project git repos.

If there is no existing such tool I intend to have a go at hacking one together (probably using fsevents & written in ruby) and would welcome any feedback about how to approach it.

EDIT: I'm wondering if another possibility might be to make a "file system" using [Fuse](http://osxfuse.github.io). This would restrict the location of my "metafile" to a top-level /Volumes/... path I guess, but I can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

*ninja'd by OP, sigh*

Linux has a layer called "FUSE" meant for writing filesystems in user-space, which has been ported to various BSDs including OS X, formerly through [MacFuse](https://code.google.com/p/macfuse/); nowadays it seems [OSXFUSE](http://osxfuse.github.io/) is the current implementation.

FUSE is a little different from your "metafile" idea – it works with entire filesystems, not just single files, so the API is somewhat low-level.

However, it's much easier than writing a kernel module or a kext – there are Perl, Python, Ruby bindings for writing custom FUSE servers. It would probably take a few hours to write a simple FUSE filesystem that serves one auto-generated file.

(The most popular FUSE server is *sshfs*, which connects to another server using SFTP and exposes that as a local filesystem, but there are dozens more – ntfs-3g (a popular NTFS driver); wikipediafs (exposes Wikipedia articles as files); curlftpfs; fuseiso; ...)

Comment: I haven't found a good basic tutorial yet -- know of any?